# How to edit index.php to open my website all with a particular directory?

Tags: php

I have just re-installed a backup of my website. I want my index.php to function per default.
For example `/sedemo/` directory is installed as follows:

**Problem:**

Before my website crashed I had the folders and files ALL under the `/sedemo/` directory. This is the way I still want it - all folders to be under `se427` - to make it easier for all future upgrades from socialengine.com.

The way Social Engine had it by default is that ALL FOLDERS/ FILES that are associated with the Social Engine Scripts are placed under `sedemo` directory and this the way I still want it as well...and this was what it was before my website crashed.

As such I will appreciate to `index.php` such that all required folders are all utilized under `sedemo` directory.

In order words, the `index.php` "file" should point to the `index.php` under the application and then link the `public` and "temporary folders all under the `httpdocs//sedemo/`
as shown below:

```
httpdocs/.htaccess
httpdocs/index.php

httpdocs/sedemo/application/index.php
sedemo/public/
sedemo/temporary/
```

Can someone assist with the editing of my `index.php`?

Comment: I don't understand... was this translated?

Comment: I don't quite understand your sample not how to include

Comment: I don't quite understand your explin code or how to implement it. However, below is my own .htaccess code:

Answer (score 1):

to your initial directory put `.htaccess` file which will redirect you page into directory you want to be served. You can use also `virtual host` to achieve this, without redirecting.

**EDIT:**

Redirecting with `.htaccess` is completely described [here](http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/redirecting-a-web-folder-directory-to-another-in-htaccess/).

So for example if you want to redirect `/var/www/my_directory_with_index_php` to another directory like `/var/www/my_directory_with_index_php/subdirectory/`, just put .htaccess into the first one with rules described in the link above.

You must have `mod_rewrite` enabled. [See documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

The your `.htaccesss` file could look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)/my_directory_with_index_php/(.*)$ $1/my_directory_with_index_php/subdirectory/$2 [R,L]
```

Virtual hosts are described [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html).

Comment: most probably only .htaccess as an option

Comment: Kamil, Could you please provide a sample of what the .ahtaccess code should look like?

Comment: Virtual host...never heard of that. How can this be implemented ?. I'm a novice.

Comment: I don't quite understand your explanation code or how to implement it. please provide full httpdocs example: For example assuming that www.abc.com is my domain and httpdocs is in the root and then my social engine script is named /sedemo/application.index.php

Comment: do you have access to server configuration on that domain?